# pkg load sockets in Octave

Tags: sockets, installation, octave

When I try to install the `sockets` package in Octave, the error below occurred:

```
octave:4> pkg install -forge sockets
In file included from socket.cc:22:0:
c:\octave\octave~1.1\include\octave-4.4.1\octave\toplev.h:28:2: warning: #warning "toplev.h has been deprecated; use interpreter.h instead" [-Wcpp]
 #warning "toplev.h has been deprecated; use interpreter.h instead"
```

How can I debug it?

Answer (score 2):

This is not an error, it's a deprecation warning. The package itself will have installed properly.

If you'd like, you could file a bug report at the octave bug tracker; but I'm sure the maintainer of that package is probably already aware of it.